# Woodworking shops in Montreal,Canada

Tags: table-saw, plywood, cutting, shop

I arrived in Canada/Montreal about a week ago, and want to make/ create some wooden projects, therefore I went to some wood suppliers like HomeDepot, RenoDepot, etc.

The average price of 8*4*3/4 plywood is around $50, but the cost of each cut in that stores is about $2. as far as I checked my plan, the price of my project's cutting is almost double of material. Another option is to rent the portable Table-Saw for $40 daily. without any doubt, they are not accurate not suitable for cutting sheets.

Are there any shop/Workshop in Montreal that gives me/rent their facilities to cut these sheets myself?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to a commercial referral rather than wood working

Answer (score 2):

I did a quick search using the terms "makerspace toronto" and came up with a number of links. One of the links is a [collection of locations](https://www.makodesign.com/blog/2018/08/31/top-makerspace-toronto/) in the area. In such a metropolitan area as Toronto, you'll likely find a makerspace with a table saw.

Additionally, makers in such organizations may have personally owned equipment. Our local makerspace does not have a table saw (it's a public library) but I do and so does at least one other member.

Hang around, make a friend or two and get the word out regarding your project. We makers tend to enjoy helping others make things!